# Why am I receiving ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) for destroy action? Rails 5.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a link to a custom destroy action that deletes a record through an AJAX call. The issue is, when I click the link_to button. I receive ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)): Normally, it would work without issue. But, I am unable to recognize what the cause of the error is. The record that I am searching for, is associated with the current object in scope. How do I successfully destroy records with the unshare action given the parameters?

I tried changing the action's parameters to find the record in question and delete the object. Only one approach worked, and that was with a where() clause, that allowed me to find the object with the original_post id and current_user.id. Lastly, I created an **unshare.js.erb**, which correlates with the action.

**_post.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to unshare_post_path(post), method: :delete, remote: true, style: 'text-decoration: none;' do %>
   <i class="fas fa-share-square fa-2x post-charm-bar-icon-color"></i>
<% end %>
```

**unshare.js.erb**

```
$('#share_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "posts/share", :locals => {:post => @post}) %>');
$("#share_<%= @post.id %>").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$(this).remove();
});
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
 def unshare
    post = Post.where(original_post_id: @post.id).where(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
      if post.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: "You've successfully unshared the Post" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts, on: :collection do
    member do
      post :share
      delete :unshare
    end
  end
```

**Expected Results**: When you click unshare, the destroy action initiates successfully and the post fades away.

**Actual Results**: I receive an error stating that the destroy action requires 1 parameter, but 0 was given in 'block in unshare'.

```
Started DELETE "/posts/472epAQhoQfg/unshare" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-09 19:22:02 -0500
Processing by PostsController#unshare as JS
  Parameters: {"on"=>:collection, "id"=>"472epAQhoQfg"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."hash_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["hash_id", "472epAQhoQfg"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)



ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)):

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:70:in `block in unshare'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:69:in `unshare'
```

**UPDATE SERVER LOG**

```
Started GET "/new_notification_check.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-09 20:40:12 -0500
Started DELETE "/posts/472epAQhoQfg/unshare" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-09 20:40:13 -0500
Processing by NotificationsController#check_for_new_notifications as JSON
Processing by PostsController#unshare as JS
  Parameters: {"on"=>:collection, "id"=>"472epAQhoQfg"}
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (3.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Notification Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "notifications".* FROM "notifications" 
WHERE "notifications"."recipient_id" = $1 AND "notifications"."read_at" IS NULL  [["recipient_id", 2]]
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 1.8ms | ActiveRecord: 5.0ms)


  Post Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."hash_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["hash_id", "472epAQhoQfg"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."original_post_id" IS NULL AND "posts"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
  Impression Destroy (493.9ms)  DELETE FROM "impressions" WHERE "impressions"."impressionable_id" = $1 AND "impressions"."impressionable_type" = $2  [["impressionable_id", 1], ["impressionable_type", "Post"]]
  ActsAsVotable::Vote Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."votable_id" = $1 AND "votes"."votable_type" = $2  [["votable_id", 1], ["votable_type", "Post"]]
  Comment Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."commentable_id" = $1 AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $2 AND "comments"."parent_id" IS NULL  [["commentable_id", 1], ["commentable_type", "Post"]]
  Comment Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" = $1  [["post_id", 1]]
  Post Destroy (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
   (38.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts
Completed 302 Found in 701ms (ActiveRecord: 554.9ms)


Started DELETE "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2019-02-09 20:40:16 -0500

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/posts"):
```

**UPDATE 2**

**posts_controller/share action**

```
def share
    post = current_user.posts.new(original_post_id: @post.id)
    if post.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to :back}
        format.js {render action: 'share'}
      end
    end
 end
```

**share.js.erb**

```
$('#share_<%= @post.id %>').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "posts/share", :locals => {:post => @post}) %>');
```

Comment: After raking my routes, I see **PATH**: /posts/:id/unshare. **Action**: posts#unshare. **path url**: unshare_post

Comment: How are you setting ```@post``` in the unshare method? And where is going to return an ActiveRecord::Relation, so you have to pull out the post you want. Maybe by chaining .first to the call.

Comment: I updated the question body. Update 2 shows how the share action is implemented. It works, but it doesn't render the **share.js.erb** response. As in refreshes the view with the new button state and change to count.

Comment: But how are you setting `@post` in the unshare action? I see you're using `@post`, but you have to set @post somewhere. Are you using a before_action to set it?

Comment: In the show view. The @post variable is being used. Should I remove the @ on post and leave it as **post** only? before_action :set_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy share unshare ]. Btw, I will try again without share unshare in the before_action.

Comment: I’m trying with the @post variable now

Comment: If you want to use `post` in the view, you have to set it as `@post`, not `post`.

Comment: I’m iterating over all posts.each do |post|

Comment: I got it working now. I believe. I just have to get the AJAX to remove the post. Thank you for guiding me.

Answer (score 1):

`Post.where` returns collection of records, so that means `post` variable contains multiple records.

you have to call `post.delete_all` or call `#destroy` method to each post instance, for example: `post.each {|p| p.destroy }`

however to fix your code, it should be

```
  def unshare
    post = Post.find_by(original_post_id: @post.original_post_id, user_id: current_user.id)
    if post.blank?
      respond_to do |format|
        if post.destroy
          format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: "Post is not found" }
        end
      end
      return
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if post.destroy
        format.html { redirect_to posts_path, notice: "You've successfully unshared the Post" }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: The changes led to the deletion of the record, but I'm receiving a new error. Check the updated post. It rolled back, it didn't delete. I apologize.

Comment: the only error in server log is `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/posts"):`. Post deletion is succeed based on following log:
` Post Destroy (1.0ms)  DELETE FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1  [["id", 1]]
   (38.0ms)  COMMIT`

Comment: I was able to find the post in question by using this query. **>> Post.where(original_post_id: 5).where(user_id: 2)
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."original_post_id" = $1 AND "posts"."user_id" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["original_post_id", 5], ["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 11]]
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 17, body_text: nil, photo: nil, user_id: 2, created_at: "2019-02-10 00:00:24", updated_at: "2019-02-10 00:00:24", post_id: nil, original_post_id: 5, hash_id: "ZhAtm6GVq2pi,>]>**

Comment: When I do **Post.find(17).destroy**, it works without issue.

Comment: if you use '#where' method, then you should get the first/last post to delete from array of posts, because `where` method returns array. it should be `Post.where(original_post_id: 5).where(user_id: 2).last`

Comment: and another problem on client side is, post ID is missing, so your client app do request to DELETE /posts, it should be DELETE /posts/{id}